# Optimize .NET web service DB record selection

Tags: c#, mysql, web-services

I am planning a web service (.NET asmx) which I need to optimize as much as possible.
The web service returns 10 random records (each call from a client needs to be random) from the database (Mysql) according to a parameter passed from the client. Each paramter (1-12) holds ~2000 records in the DB.

solutions:

1. Querying the DB (which will be indexed by the parameter) and just return the result.
2. Cache the table from the DB to a .net Datatable and select by Linq (~15,000 records).
3. Cache the DB into 12 .net DataTables, each for possible param, and query the Datatable
   with Linq.

What is the best way to preform this task? I would love to hear other ideas!

Best Regards, Udi

Comment: Why would you use asmx? WCF is the prefered service stack nowadays.

Comment: @rene - Actually, WebApi is starting to replace wcf for simple requests.

Comment: I'm adding new functionality (method) to an existing web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cache the data into 12 strongly-typed arrays. That removes all processing besides selecting 10 random records from a simple array. It doesn't get faster than that.

Don't use data tables. Why would you? They can only be slower than strongly typed lists/arrays of a custom class.

How to optimize selecting 10 random items is a different question, though, that surely has been answered already.

Comment: Thanks!
I need to return the result as a Json to the client. Is Storing each object, as the json string, in the array, and then concat the N random Json strings and send this string to the client will be efficient?

Comment: @UdiI, that sounds like a very nice idea assuming that you really need to get the most performance possible. I recommend it. Serialization can be expensive. We have optimized this now to a great extent. You should probably load-test the site and run a profiler on it. You will notice that ASP.NET overhead is greater than your own code! Try to get rid of some of it.